# Saving multiple images with the Original name after introducing Gaussian Blur

Tags: python, opencv

I have Python code which reads 54 images from the folder named Disparity and applies Gaussian Blur to these images and after that writes them to a location. The code is given below:

```
path = "Disparity/*.png"

for bb,file in enumerate (glob.glob(path)):
    a = cv2.imread(file)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(a, (5, 5), random.randint(3, 10))
    cv2.imwrite('GaussianBlur{}.jpg'.format(bb), blur)
```

After running this code, what I'm expecting is that it reads the first image as `a.png` and the second image as `b.png`.

These two images should be saved as `a_GaussianBlur0.jpg` and `b_GaussianBlur.jpg`.

Please tell me how I could get the original name along with the edited one?

Comment: Sir I didn't get what you are saying but Number of images does not matter what I want is If I apply gaussian blur to a batch of images these should be written with their original names

Comment: Do you want to save images in the same folder but after preprocessing? Does this code run without any error?

Comment: Yes this runs without any error 
I'm not writing them to the same location 
the directory structure is like -- Folder 'A' which contains a folder Disparity(this contains all images) and a Gaussian.py file 
I'm reading from Disparity folder and writing them to A folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract just the filename from a given file path, you can use the Python [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=basename#os.path.basename) function. This will also give you an extension. The [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=basename#os.path.splitext) could then be used to return just the base file name. This can then be used to construct your new output filename:

```
import os

path = "Disparity/*.png"

for index, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(path)):
    a = cv2.imread(filename)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(a, (5, 5), random.randint(3, 10))
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    cv2.imwrite(f'{basename}_Gaussian{index}.png')
```

So if you had three files `['abc.png', 'def.png', 'ghi.png']`, your output filenames would be:

```
abc_Gussian0.png
def_Gussian1.png
ghi_Gussian2.png
```

Comment: Thanks Sir,
For your help

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my Own Question...
I have to do the following changes in my code:

The last line of code which is : ->
cv2.imwrite('GaussianBlur{}.jpg'.format(bb), blur )

This should be like: ->
cv2.imwrite(file+'GaussianBlur{}.jpg'.format(bb), blur )

I have added file here because all names of the files that are read from the Disparity folder are inside the File variable. By adding the file I'm actually adding the original name to individual image